# Android strange layout positioning

Tags: android, android-layout

I have strange issue with layout positioning.
Here are 2 screens.

[image]

[image]

As you can see on first screenCapture elements takes 2 line.
The difference in xml layout between is `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"` on first image and `android:paddingRight="10dp"` on the second image.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_event_date_and_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/date_time_left">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_date"
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_event_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_event_date"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_date"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_time"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_event_date"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_event_time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_event_time"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" // Here is difference
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_time"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_event_remind"
        style="@style/MaterialButtonBorderLess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="@string/event_remind"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

One more strange thing is that on screen resolution 768 x 1280 - everything is fine. But on 720 x 1280 - only padding works correctly.

So, i am interesting why does it happening, and what should i do to prevent this.

ADDITION

If I use

```
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:singleLine="true"
```

The effect is next:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:singleLine="true"` on the label to ensure that it never wraps no matter what its size is.

Comment: If i am using `singleLine` the text is cutting, and a don't want to see this behaviour. I can provide screen tomorrow.

Comment: I made a screen capture of `singleLine` effect.

Answer (score 0):

use this feature on your layout.

android:singleLine="true"

Comment: If i am using `singleLine` the text is cutting, and a don't want to see this behaviour. I can provide screen tomorrow.